# Как получить значение следующей строки из бд и вывести её в переменную?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть две вот такие таблицы: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d307e . Подскажите, как, при добавлении новых данных в main, выдать значение из таблицы color (col1, col2, col3 ...) в зависимости о того, какое значение cololr было до этого?
То есть: я добавляю данные в main

```
$nnomer = "lux";
const SQL_INSERT_MAIN = '
INSERT INTO main (namenomer, datestart, dateend, color) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
';
$addmt = $pdo->prepare(SQL_INSERT_MAIN);
$add = $addmt->execute([$nnomer, $datestart, $dateend, $color]);
```

Значение $nnomer у меня равно lux. В базе данных у lux последнее значение было col3, поэтому при новом добавлении color должен быть равен col4. Как только color в таблице main дойдёт до col6, то пр новом добавлении color будет равен col1. И так по-кругу. 
Если бы значение $nnomer у меня было равно vip, то color должен был быть равен col2, так как последнее значение color - col1. Это такой некий auto_increment... Как такое реализовать?

Comment: номер цвета равен единица плюс остаток от деления количества предыдущих записей (подходящих по условию) на количество цветов. И данный параметр всегда можно вычислить, зачем его хранить в БД. И если вдруг у вас запись удаляется, то что происходит с цветами у последующих записей

Comment: Получи последний color, получи его id, прибавь 1, при необходимости закольцуй.

Comment: @Mike , не меняются цвета у предыдущих записей. Как были, так и остаются. Новый цвет просто всегда зависит от предыдущего. Если прошлый col2, то настоящий col3, а следующий col4.

Comment: @Akina , да я попытался, да фигня одна. Тут же нужно в один sql уложиться...

Comment: Кстати, а что такое "последнее значение" как найти какая запись была последней. у нее какая то определенная дата или может максимальный id или еще что. И я надеюсь значения поля lux строго последовательны, т.е. id у col2 на 1 больше, чем у col1

Comment: намутил костыль и избавился от col. просто цифры теперь по-кругу ходят)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала Вам нужно определиться с понятием "последняя запись". Предположим, что это запись с максимальным `id`.

Дальше весь вопрос в том, как получить эту запись. Я бы решал задачу через триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_main_bi BEFORE INSERT ON main
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET NEW.`color` = col1;

  SELECT
    IF(mn.`color` = col6, col1, mn.`color` + 1)
  FROM
    main mn
  WHERE
    mn.`namenomer` = NEW.`namenomer` AND
    mn.`id` = (SELECT MAX(mx.`id`) FROM main mx WHERE mx.`namenomer` = NEW.`namenomer`)
  INTO
    NEW.`color`;
END;
```

И далее

```
INSERT INTO main (namenomer, datestart, dateend) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

может стоит в таблице main поле color сделать int и сделать внешним ключом к color.id

тогда можно будет перед вставкой определить id из таблице color запросом

```
select case when m.id_color = c.max_id then 1 else m.id_color + 1 end case 
from main m 
left join (select max(id) as  max_id from color) c on 1 = 1
order by id desc limit 1
```